# Why does Qt list pane indicate there is a selection, even when the user does not select an item and no item appears as selected?

Tags: qt

I do not understand why a selection is returned by my `QListView`, even when the user does not select an item, no item appears as selected, and `clearSelection()` is called on the pane before it is displayed.

Here is the relevant code that creates the list items:

```
class WidgetInstanceIdentifier {...} // This class is properly registered with Qt

listpane = new QListView(...);
QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel(listpane);

int index = 0;
std::for_each(vg_list.cbegin(), vg_list.cend(), [&](WidgetInstanceIdentifier const & vg)
{

    QStandardItem * item = new QStandardItem();
    std::string text = "...";
    item->setText(text.c_str());
    item->setEditable(false);
    item->setCheckable(false);
    QVariant v;
    v.setValue(vg);
    item->setData(v);
    model->setItem( index, item );

    ++index;

});

model->sort(0);

listpane->setModel(model);

listpane->clearSelection();
```

Here is a screenshot showing the dialog at the moment I click "OK".  Notice that neither item in the list pane is selected:

[image: No selection]

... And here is the relevant code that tests for the selection:

```
QItemSelectionModel * listpane_selectionModel = listpane->selectionModel();
QModelIndex selectedIndex = listpane_selectionModel->currentIndex();
if (!selectedIndex.isValid())
{
    // This block of code is not hit!!!!!!
    // I expect it would be hit
}

QVariant vg_variant = listpaneModel->item(selectedIndex.row())->data();

// The following variable is properly set to correct data representing
// the first item in the list
vg_to_use = vg_variant.value<WidgetInstanceIdentifier>();
```

As noted in the code, the block of code that I expect to be hit in the case of "no selection" - the `if (!selectedIndex.isValid()) {...}` block - is not hit.  Instead, the first item in the list is returned, as though it is selected.  This is not desired!  The user has no way to know which item is *really* being selected.

What am I misunderstanding?  Why does Qt seem to report that there is a valid selection, even with no item selected in the list?  What is the *proper* way to check if there is *really* no item selected?

Comment: You fell to a name-reinforced bug. You name something one way, yet it's not what you've named it. Namely, `listpane_selectionModel->currentIndex()` has *nothing much* to do with selection. It's just the currently active index, but it's not necessarily selected. To iterate the list of selected indexes, do: `foreach (QModelIndex idx, listpane_selectionMode->selectedIndexes()) { .... }`

Comment: I appreciate the comment!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think selected item and current item are not the same things. Although, in some cases current item can be selected too, but this is not necessarily. Usually the current item indicated by the dashed outline in the view. Thus, if you want to check selection items count do it with `QItemSelectionModel::selectedIndexes()` function, i.e.:

```
QModelIndexList selected = listpane_selectionModel->selectedIndexes();
if (!selected.isEmpty()) {
    // do something
}
```